# Where can I find a KML file for Scottish Datazones 2011?

Tags: kml

I'm working on mapping my data in Google Fusion and would like to have a KML file for Scottish Datazones 2011 so I can do some work on deprivation.  I can't find one and I don't have the skills to work out how to make one.

Comment: How far have you gotten on your own? Have you found https://data.gov.uk/dataset/data-zone-boundaries-2011 for example?

Comment: I've been to that website - it seems the shapefile has no data.

Comment: I downloaded http://sedsh127.sedsh.gov.uk/Atom_data/ScotGov/ZippedShapefiles/SG_DataZoneBdry_2011.zip, unzipped it, and ran `ogrinfo -al SG_DataZone_Bdry_2011.shp` on one of the unzipped file. There were 90,719 lines of data.

Comment: Thanks - I'm a bit new and lost on this!  It appears I did better last year and had actually got as far as the zipped files last year when I tried this as I have these files (sorry my memory is terrible) but I got stuck trying to convert it to a kml file.

Comment: google "shp2kml"